# Is there a simple way to have images appear as you scroll similar to this website (https://publicofficial.co/)?

Tags: html, css

I am not sure exactly what to search or what this effect is called so I am asking here. I tried researching it but am not able to find what I need. I want to achieve images to appear as I scroll similar to this website (https://publicofficial.co/). It tends to work as I scroll upward and downwards and I think is pretty cool. Is there a simple way to achieve this.

Also, I was inspecting it an looking to build the mobile version first, so I don't know if its any different for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Add a wheel roll listener:

`document.body.addEventListener("wheel", (e) => onMouseWheelRolled(e), { passive: true } )`

(I don't know if `passive` is required here but it doesn't hurt.)

Now add the named function to handle this event:

```
function onMouseWheelRolled(e) { 
    // e is a WheelEvent object and has members:
    //
    // deltaX   The horizontal (x-axis) scroll amount of the wheel
    // deltaY   The vertical (y-axis) scroll amount of the wheel
    // deltaZ   The z-axis scroll amount of the wheel
    // deltaMode    The unit of measurements (pixels, lines or pages)
    
}
```

Now you can move your images around by changing their `style`'s `top`, `left` properties, etc.

This does *not* require scroll bars to be present to work.

Comment: This doesn't work on mobile. (I also think it's a bad thing to try to do in the first place, so there's not really any loss there.)

Comment: Thank you, I am new to web development and don't know much except some basic html and css. I will try and see what I can do with this.